# Laravel dynamic return from controller?

Tags: dynamic, laravel, crud, laravel-routing

I need to return a different view from a controller depending on the route that is requested.

**For example:** in my application I have clients, devices and campaigns. All have CRUD's created, but in some cases I want to do something like "view clients, delete his campaign and returning to the clients view" but my campaignsController@delete returns to campaigns by default.

The idea is not rewrite the same controller only changing the route of returning, does Laravel have something to help with this?

Thank you

Comment: Could you share some code? Related routers and controllers methods would help.

Comment: Without seeing some examples, it's difficult to help, but you may be able to use `Route::uri()` which would return the URI the user is on.  You could potentially use that to figure out what you need to redirect to.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. If you want the controller to do something different..change the return?

Comment: @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro, uses a perfect example with his code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel will not control the whole flow of your application. If you have a campaign delete router:

```
Route::delete('campaign/{id}');
```

and it returns to campaigns

```
class CampaignController extends Controller {

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $c = Campaign::find($id);

        $c->delete();

        return Redirect::route('campaigns');
    }

}
```

You will have to trick your route to make it go to wherever you need to, there should be dozens of ways of doing that, this is a very simple one:

```
Route::delete('campaign/{id}/{returnRoute?}');

class CampaignController extends Controller {

    public function delete($id, $returnRoute = null)
    {
        $returnRoute = $returnRoute ?: 'campaigns';

        $c = Campaign::find($id);

        $c->delete();

        return Redirect::route($returnRoute);
    }

}
```

And create the links in those pages by using the return route option:

```
link_to_route('campaign.delete', 'Delete Campaign', ['id' => $id, 'returnRoute' => 'clients'])
```

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your response.
I thought that another solution would be access the value of Request ::fullUrl() and make comparisons before return, but I think it can hit good practices.